# Android: Use webview instead of browser: Help convert my sample code

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview

Hi my current sample code uses and opens up browser when I click a particular item in list view
I traced my piece of code to be using adapter etc... I have read about webview in this particular link
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

but I am not sure on how exactly I need to replace my code methods below to webview. Please help.
(Note just in case u need to know what getLink method is it just parses an xml to find the node of link)

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
//Get reference to our ListView
sitesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sitesList);

//Set the click listener to launch the browser when a row is clicked.
sitesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,long id) {


        String url = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getLink();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below link, you will get small example demo for webview.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Check below code, replace below code to your existing code:

```
 String url = mAdapter.getItem(pos).getLink();
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("URL",Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
```

After did this, create new class WebViewActivity, declare webview in xml, and then refer the link given, you will get idea.

Comment: Im sorry pratik it wasnt easy for me to replace my existing code that has a listviewitem click event. i am newbie and really like some help here. do i need to create a new layout for webview and how to link it to my mainactivity code